# Chanukah greetings proper form

Tags: hebrew, grammar-dikduk, chanuka

why is the greeting for Hanukah
חג אורים שמח "chag urim samach"
And not חג אורות?

Comment: I've never heard this greeting. Who says it?

Comment: Never heard of it. It might be secular Israeli, in which case we wouldn't have an answer for you in this forum.

Comment: IIRC, it's pronounced אוּרים, not אוֹרים, which might be the difference

Comment: https://hebrew-academy.org.il/2019/12/17/%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%95%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%AA/